# text over images in html css

Tags: html, css

i am trying to put text over image it works but is there a better way to do it. should i use a different html tag for the text. 
any suggestions

http://jsfiddle.net/8rDda/

```
  body{
    background-color:#F0F0F0 ;
    color:#000305;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    font-family: Arial,'Lucida Sans Unicode';
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
    width:80%;
     margin:2% auto;
}


.main {
    width:45%; 
    height:300px;
    background-color: #20b2aa;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.main img{
    width:80%; 
    height:auto;
    margin: 6% 10%; 
    float: left;
}

.main h2 { 
    color:white;
   position: absolute; 
   margin:50px;
   margin-left: 50px;
   width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, you can use p, h1 or h2, it's alright

Comment: this is totally subjective  and may depend on scenario..

Comment: I would put the image as a `background` to a `div`. Then you wouldn't have to use `position:absolute` to position the text.

Comment: There are many ways to the put text over image. you can use `:after` and `:before` pseudo element. but finally up to you. what's is your project requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8rDda/1/

I would use absolute positioning instead of float.

```
.main {
    width:45%; 
    height:300px;
    background-color: #20b2aa;
    border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative; //keep children absolutely position constrained to this element.
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.main h2 { 
    color:white;
   position: absolute; 
   margin: 6% 10%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one solution could be, that you set the image as `background-image` for your div. And edit the test in it. So you jut have a single div, which you must edit.

[http://jsfiddle.net/QX36R/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/QX36R/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `z-index` and different divs. But at last you need `position:absolute;` with different positions or `margin-top: -whatever` with `position:relative;`. There is not really a right or wrong approach to do this. As long as it works on your site, it is all fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<div>` tag means creating one div and put it on the top of image or set any position or else link it with another div which will be your image. There are plenty of things you can do with `<div>` tag.
Example.

---

```
<div style="abcd">
      top: 99;
      left: 99;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      visibility: show;">
<!-- content will go here -->
</div>
```

---